# Combining a stacked chart with a bar chart

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using reportbuilder 3

I was wondering if there was a way to combine a stacked bar chart with a normal bar chart.

I've tried a work around which, whilst serves the purpose, doesn't to me, look particularly professional. If its not possible to combine the two I'd be willing to listen to any other workarounds, for example like getting the two charts closer together, no gap in the horizontal axis, having the vertical axis of the stacked chart to mirror that of the bar chart (the bar chart currently extends past the vertical axis in the stacked chart). Any suggestions welcome.

This is my design view, stack bar chart to the left and normal bar chart to the right

[image]

This is the output

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be achievable in your scenario but as I don;t know what your data looks like, it's hard to tell.

My approach would be to arrange the dataset to contain two categories and have one category contain one series value and the main category include everything except the main series value.

To create this data I created a dataset with the following query.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ColA varchar(10), ColB varchar(10), Amount int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('Targeted', 'Cars', 1170),
('Targeted', 'Bikes', 2598),
('Targeted', 'Trains', 6515),
('Others', 'Others', 14069)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I then added a single stacked column chart as follows

[image]

This gives us the following result.

[image]

It has the advantage that the scales will be based on all amounts and its very simple to do. It may however be an issue if you need to independently format the two sets of data.